# Cannot add a JPanel Component from other class in JTabbedPane of main class, type mismatch - cannot convert from void to the called constructor

Tags: java, swing

This is the main class which has the JTabbedPane code. The line between **    ** is the line that gives me the type mismatch error.
I am trying to call the constructor from another class i.e. ChecksDB but it gives me the following type mismatch error. I am a novice for java swings and cant get rd of this error. I did view related posts, but none could help me out with this issue.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class SwingsMains {

String proj = "CSA";
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Checks";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "Settings";
final static String TEXTPANEL1 = "Emails";
final static int extraWindowWidth = 100;

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    //Create the "cards".
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel() {
        //Make the panel wider than it really needs, so
        //the window's wide enough for the tabs to stay
        //in one row.
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
            size.width += extraWindowWidth;
            return size;
        }
    };
    **ChecksDB card= new ChecksDB(proj).setVisible(true);**

    card1.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
    card1.add(new JButton("Button 3"));

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.add(new JTextField("TextField", 20));

    tabbedPane.addTab(BUTTONPANEL, card1);
    tabbedPane.addTab(TEXTPANEL, card2);

    pane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event dispatch thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    SwingsMains demo = new SwingsMains();
    demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
    try {
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the code of the ChecksDB class.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;    
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class ChecksDB extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public ChecksDB(String proj) {
  dep=proj;
  System.out.println(dep);
  initComponents();
  Show_Checks_In_JTable();  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


// get a list of checks from sql database
public ArrayList<Check> getChecksList()
{   System.out.println(dep);
   String query = "SELECT project, chktype, path, day, hour, sunday,   monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, id FROM  [dbo].[checks] where deployment='"+dep+"'";
   ArrayList<Check> checksList = new ArrayList<Check>();

   try {
       Statement st = ConnectionManager.con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
       Check check;
       while(rs.next())
       {
           check = new Check(rs.getString("project"),rs.getString("chktype"),rs.getString("path"),rs.getInt("day"),rs.getInt("hour"),rs.getInt("sunday"),rs.getInt("monday"),rs.getInt("tuesday"),rs.getInt("wednesday"),rs.getInt("thursday"),rs.getInt("friday"),rs.getInt("saturday"),rs.getInt("id"));
           checksList.add(check);
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return checksList;
}

// Display Data In JTable

public void Show_Checks_In_JTable()
{
   ArrayList<Check> list = getChecksList();
   System.out.println(list.size());
   DefaultTableModel model =     (DefaultTableModel)jTable_Display_Checks.getModel();
   Object[] row = new Object[13];
   for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
   {
       row[0] = list.get(i).getproject();
       System.out.println(row[0]);
       row[1] = list.get(i).getchktype();
       row[2] = list.get(i).getpath();
       row[3] = list.get(i).getday();
       row[4] = list.get(i).gethour();
       System.out.println(row[4]);
       row[5] = list.get(i).getsun();
       row[6] = list.get(i).getmon();
       row[7] = list.get(i).gettue();
       row[8] = list.get(i).getwed();
       row[9] = list.get(i).getthu();
       row[10] = list.get(i).getfri();
       row[11] = list.get(i).getsat();
       row[12] = list.get(i).getid();

       model.addRow(row);
   }
}

// Execute The Insert Save And Delete Querys
public void executeSQlQuery(String query, String message)
{

   try{
       Statement st = ConnectionManager.con.createStatement();
       if((st.executeUpdate(query)) == 1)
       {
           // refresh jtable data
           DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable_Display_Checks.getModel();
           model.setRowCount(0);
           Show_Checks_In_JTable();

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data "+message+" Successfully");
       }else{
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Not "+message);
       }
   }catch(Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}


private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabelnew = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField_project = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_chktype = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_path = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_day = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_hour = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_sun = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_mon = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_tue = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_wed = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_thu = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_fri = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_sat = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_id = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField_id.setEditable(false);
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable_Display_Checks = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton_Save = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton_Addnew = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton_Delete = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextField_project.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_project.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_projectActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_chktype.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_chktype.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_chktypeActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_path.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_path.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_pathActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_day.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_day.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_dayActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_hour.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_hour.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_hourActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_sun.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_sun.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_sunActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_mon.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_mon.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_monActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_tue.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_tue.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_tueActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_wed.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_wed.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_wedActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_thu.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_thu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_thuActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_fri.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_fri.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_friActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_sat.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_sat.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_satActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField_id.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField_id.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField_idActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });


    jTable_Display_Checks.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Protocol", "Checktype", "Path", "Day", "Hour", "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","ID"
        }
    ));
    jTable_Display_Checks.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jTable_Display_ChecksMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable_Display_Checks);



    jButton_Save.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton_Save.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jButton_Save.setText("Save");
    jButton_Save.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton_SaveActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton_Delete.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton_Delete.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jButton_Delete.setText("Delete");
    jButton_Delete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton_DeleteActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton_Addnew.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton_Addnew.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jButton_Addnew.setText("Add New");
    jButton_Addnew.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton_AddnewActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });




private void jTextField_projectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                    

private void jTextField_chktypeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                   

private void jTextField_pathActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_dayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_hourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_sunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_monActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_tueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_wedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_thuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_friActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_satActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void jTextField_idActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              



// show jtable row data in jtextfields in the mouse clicked event
private void jTable_Display_ChecksMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                  
   // Get The Index Of The Slected Row 
    int i = jTable_Display_Checks.getSelectedRow();

    TableModel model = jTable_Display_Checks.getModel();

     // Display Selected Row In JTexteFields
    jTextField_project.setText(model.getValueAt(i,0).toString());

    jTextField_chktype.setText(model.getValueAt(i,1).toString());

    jTextField_path.setText(model.getValueAt(i,2).toString());

    jTextField_day.setText(model.getValueAt(i,3).toString());

    jTextField_hour.setText(model.getValueAt(i,4).toString());

    jTextField_sun.setText(model.getValueAt(i,5).toString());

    jTextField_mon.setText(model.getValueAt(i,6).toString());

    jTextField_tue.setText(model.getValueAt(i,7).toString());

    jTextField_wed.setText(model.getValueAt(i,8).toString());

    jTextField_thu.setText(model.getValueAt(i,9).toString());

    jTextField_fri.setText(model.getValueAt(i,10).toString());

    jTextField_sat.setText(model.getValueAt(i,11).toString());

    jTextField_id.setText(model.getValueAt(i,12).toString());


}                                                 

// Button Insert



// Button Save
private void jButton_SaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                               
   if(jTextField_id.getText().isEmpty())
       {
       String query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[checks](project, chktype, path, day, hour, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday,deployment) VALUES ('"+jTextField_project.getText()+"','"+jTextField_chktype.getText()+"','"+jTextField_path.getText()+"',"+jTextField_day.getText()+","+jTextField_hour.getText()+","+jTextField_sun.getText()+","+jTextField_mon.getText()+","+jTextField_tue.getText()+","+jTextField_wed.getText()+","+jTextField_thu.getText()+","+jTextField_fri.getText()+","+jTextField_sat.getText()+",'"+dep+"')";

       executeSQlQuery(query, "Inserted");

       }
   else {

       String query = "UPDATE [dbo].[checks] SET project='"+jTextField_project.getText()+"',chktype='"+jTextField_chktype.getText()+"',path='"+jTextField_path.getText()+"', day= "+jTextField_day.getText()+",hour= "+jTextField_hour.getText()+",sunday= "+jTextField_sun.getText()+",monday="+jTextField_mon.getText()+",tuesday="+jTextField_tue.getText()+",wednesday= "+jTextField_wed.getText()+", thursday= "+jTextField_thu.getText()+",friday= "+jTextField_fri.getText()+",saturday= "+jTextField_sat.getText()+" WHERE id = "+jTextField_id.getText()+"";

       executeSQlQuery(query, "Updated");
  }
 }                                              


// Button Delete
 private void jButton_DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String query = "DELETE FROM [dbo].[checks] WHERE id = "+jTextField_id.getText()+"";
     executeSQlQuery(query, "Deleted");
     jTextField_project.setText("");
    jTextField_chktype.setText("");
    jTextField_path.setText("");
    jTextField_day.setText("");
    jTextField_hour.setText("");
    jTextField_sun.setText("");
    jTextField_mon.setText("");
    jTextField_tue.setText("");
    jTextField_wed.setText("");
    jTextField_thu.setText("");
    jTextField_fri.setText("");
    jTextField_sat.setText("");
    jTextField_id.setText("");
 }                                              


 private void jButton_AddnewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    jTextField_project.setText("");
    jTextField_chktype.setText("");
    jTextField_path.setText("");
    jTextField_day.setText("");
    jTextField_hour.setText("");
    jTextField_sun.setText("");
    jTextField_mon.setText("");
    jTextField_tue.setText("");
    jTextField_wed.setText("");
    jTextField_thu.setText("");
    jTextField_fri.setText("");
    jTextField_sat.setText("");
    jTextField_id.setText("");
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */


 // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
 private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Delete;
 private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Save;
 private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Addnew;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
 private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelnew;
 private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
 private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private javax.swing.JTable jTable_Display_Checks;
  private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_project;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_chktype;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_path;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_day;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_hour;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_sun;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_mon;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_tue;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_wed;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_thu;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_fri;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_sat;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_id;
private static String dep;

 // End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Comment: For future reference, faster and more complete help, please read about what and how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ChecksDB card= new ChecksDB(proj).setVisible(true);
```

`JFrame.setVisible` is a void method (doesn't return anything). In order to use this method **and** have a reference to the ChecksDB instance first create the instance, then use the reference to call the method

```
ChecksDB card= new ChecksDB(proj);
card.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. But now when I try to add it to the tabbed pane, it gives me this error. " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container "